# TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, search

I am getting the error:

> StudentsAttendanceCreateComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertData' of undefined at students-attendance-create.component.ts:96 at Array.forEach ()

```
submitForm(form: NgForm) {
let cursoID: number;

Object.keys(form.value).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === 'cursoId') {
    cursoID = form.value[key];
  }
});

Object.keys(form.value).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key !== 'cursoId') {
    const json = {
      EstudianteId: key,
      asistencia: form.value[key],
      cursoId: cursoID
    };
    this.insertData(json);
  }
});
}



insertData(json: any) {
this.service.studentsAsistencia(json)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.openSnackBar('Datos insertados correctamente.', 'OK');
  });
// this.clearForm();
}
```

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Try switching to an arrow function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` takes a callback function, `this` is not available inside unless you bind it. One way to do it is through [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `()=>` does bind it automatically.

```
Object.keys(form.value).forEach((key) => {
  if (key !== 'cursoId') {
    const json = {
      EstudianteId: key,
      asistencia: form.value[key],
      cursoId: cursoID
    };
    this.insertData(json);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its reference error. If you want to use the component variable or method inside a callback, you should use lambda (arrow) function instead of using literal or anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `this` keyword inside the callback function, you should use an arrow function, your code should look like this:

```
submitForm(form: NgForm) {

let cursoID: number;

Object.keys(form.value).forEach((key) => {
  if (key === 'cursoId') {
    cursoID = form.value[key];
  }
});

Object.keys(form.value).forEach((key) => {
  if (key !== 'cursoId') {
    const json = {
      EstudianteId: key,
      asistencia: form.value[key],
      cursoId: cursoID
    };
    this.insertData(json);
  }
});
}



insertData(json: any) {
this.service.studentsAsistencia(json)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.openSnackBar('Datos insertados correctamente.', 'OK');
  });
// this.clearForm();
}
```

you can read about the differences in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/7269215